# Excel VBA - Function works in a Sub but not in the worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have like no experience with Excel and tried to write a function in VBA, where I can import another Excel file (given as a String as an argument) within the same folder like the Excel file I'm writing the function in. Code below:

```vb
Function SumNumberWorkbook(workbookName As String, zelle As String, gesuchteZahl As String) As Long
    Dim total As Long
    Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim targetFilePath As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    total = 0
    
    targetFilePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & workbookName
    If Dir(targetFilePath) <> "" Then
        Set targetWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(targetFilePath)
        For Each ws In targetWorkbook.Sheets
            If Not ws Is Nothing Then
                If InStr(1, ws.Range(zelle).Value, gesuchteZahl, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                    total = total + 1
                End If
            End If
        Next ws
        targetWorkbook.Close False
    Else
        MsgBox "File not found: " & targetFilePath, vbExclamation
        Exit Function
    End If
    SumNumberWorkbook = total
End Function

Sub SumNumberWorkbookTest()
    Dim result As Long
    result = SumNumberWorkbook("Allgemeiner Teil.xlsm", "D5", "1")
    MsgBox result
End Sub
```

I bet there are lot of improvements for the logic, but the main problem is that it doesn't work in the worksheet. The only thing I get is a `#VALUE!` error.

I wrote other functions before this one and they worked fine, so I know how the syntax should work. When I use the `Sub` I wrote below the function everything works fine and I get the correct results in the MsgBox.

In the worksheet I type: `=SumNumberWorkbook("Allgemeiner Teil.xlsm";"D5";"1")`
The file has a German name if you are curious ^^

What could the problem be? I'm glad for any help I can get!